# Finding sequences of same elements in a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering, vector

I am trying to effectively find a number which tells me the number of sequences of ones in a vector of zeros and ones. For example, consider the vector:

```
{1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1}
```

My question is, how many  `{1,1}` does it contain, while I don't want to consider {1,1,1} like  2 times series of {1,1}. So the answer should be 1 not 3.
Of course I want to find out answer for sequences of `{1,1,1} , {1,1,1,1}...` to the longest sequence, in some different series of zeros and ones.
Is there some nice built in function which can help me please ?

**To Addendum:**

Thanks again, yes algorithm using Tally works much better, actually a need it for this function which is calculating from vector input RQA analysis, If you have some suggestion how to speed up I would be glad. I want to use it on vector of length 10^4 and now it takes on my machine like 70 seconds.

```
ClearAll[Rp1];
Rp1[data_] := 
 Module[{rr, N1, idx, R, SR, RR, DDE, DET, i, j, DE}, 
  rr = N[Variance[data]];
  N1 = Length[data];
  R = ConstantArray[0, {N1, N1}];
  idx = Nearest[data -> Automatic, data, {\[Infinity], Sqrt[rr]}][[
    All, 2 ;;]];
  MapIndexed[{x, y} \[Function] R[[y, x]] = 1, idx];
  R;
  SR = Total[Total[R]];
  RR = SR/(N1*(N1 - 1));
  oneCount[list_, len_] := 
   Total@UnitStep[
     ListCorrelate[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, len], 1, -1], 
       list, {2, -2}, 0] - len];
  DE = Total[
    Table[oneCount[Diagonal[R, i], 1], {i, 1, 
      Length[Diagonal[R, 1]]}]] ;
  DET = (SR - 2*DE )/SR;
  N[{RR, DET}]
  ]
```

Comment: If you need further speed improvements, you should probably investigate using Compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use [`SequenceCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount), but then you will need to account for sequences of 1s at the edge of the lists. An alternative is to use [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate) with a kernel like `{-1, 1, 1, -1}`. For example:

```
{-1, 1, 1, -1} . {0, 1, 1, 0}
```

> 2

With the above kernel, the only sequence of 0s and 1s that produces a 2 is `{0, 1, 1, 0}`:

```
{-1, 1, 1, -1} . #& /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]
Count[%, 2]
```

> {0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, -1, -2, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0}
>
> 1

So, the following code will count all sequences of `{0, 1, 1, 0}` in your list:

```
Total @ UnitStep[ListCorrelate[{-1,1,1,-1}, list, {2,-2}, 0] - 2]
```

> 1

We can turn this into a function, and generalize to different lengths:

```
oneCount[list_, len_] := Total @ UnitStep[
    ListCorrelate[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, len], 1, -1], list, {2, -2}, 0] - len
]
```

For example:

```
oneCount[list, 2]
oneCount[list, 3]
```

> 1
>
> 1

**Addendum**

It seems you want a tally of all of the runs of 1s. In that case it would be much faster to use a different algorithm that does a single pass over the list:

```
allSequences[list_] := Tally[
    Length /@ Split[list][[If[list[[1]]==1, 1, 2] ;; -1 ;; 2]]
]
```

For your example:

```
allSequences @ {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1}
```

> {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {1, 1}}

and for a larger example:

```
list = RandomInteger[1,10^4];

allSequences[list] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0017, {{3, 307}, {2, 623}, {1, 1248}, {4, 172}, {5, 67}, {8, 13}, {6, 
>      39}, {12, 1}, {10, 5}, {7, 14}, {9, 4}, {11, 3}}}

Comment: Many thanks, is there any chance to make this code faster, for some matrix of zeros and ones of length 10000 ?        Smat[Mat_] := (
  oneCount[list_, len_] := 
   Total@UnitStep[
     ListCorrelate[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, len], 1, -1], 
       list, {2, -2}, 0] - len];
  oo = Table[
    Table[oneCount[Diagonal[Mat, j], i], {i, 1, 
      Length[Diagonal[Mat, j]]}], {j, 1, Length[Mat] - 1}];
  Yout = Total@
    Table[Flatten[{oo[[i]], Table[0, {i - 1}]}], {i, Length[oo]}]

Comment: @MarkFoster See update